# speed up embedded matplotlib plots

Tags: matplotlib

I have a fairly complicated qt4 gui with a number of matplotlib plots as shown in the picture. Each plot plots one channel of data and there are 12 channels in total. The vertical scroll bar on the right adjusts the range of channels to plot. The problem is the gui works pretty sluggishly. When the scroll bar is moved, it takes about 2 seconds to refresh the plots. Is there any way to speed it up?

The entire code is fairly large to post here. But I am using 
matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg as the backend and use canvas.draw() to refresh each plot. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you need your plot to be interactive, outside of the +/- button on the right side of your graphs I mean?

Comment: Maybe an approach like this : https://github.com/jnsebgosselin/WHAT/blob/master/WHAT/mplFigViewer3.py might be appropriate for your application? Check out the MplViewer class. It consists in using a non-GUI backend for generating the mpl figure, converting the figure in a QPixmap and then painting it manually on a QWidget. You would lose the interactive capability of the GUI backed though, but would still be able to change your figure with the external button in your GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I don't know what do you mean by interactive. Pretty new to the python world. The +/- buttons are zoom in/out buttons.

Comment: I read something about using backends like gtkagg may speed up matplotlib. Is it related?

Comment: By interactive, I mean the zooming and panning of the axes with the mouse, for example. Maybe if you can put up a minimal working example out of your code, with like one graph, embedded in a scroll-area, with generic data, I can propose a solution derived from your example. Others will certainly have alternative simpler solution also.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Sebastien, your answer makes a lot of sense. Will study the example but it seems like I do have some interactive things involved.

Comment: To test things out, I've build a simple application with a similar setup as you are showing in your screenshot using the `backend_qt4agg` in a QScrollArea and everything is running smoothly. So I guess you are doing real-time plotting right? If so, forget about my suggestion above, it won't help at all.

Comment: Great. I tried it. it works great now with QScrollArea. Thanks a lot Jean-Sebastien.